# Liferay with JSF and Facelets

Tags: jsf, liferay-6, facelets

In a project we are using Liferay with JSF and Facelets for views.

We want to use only one portlet with many Facelets pages and many backing beans.

For that we have thought to provide a menu bar (which is right now in the portlet only, on top) outside of the portlet and from there we need to show appropriate pages based on user selection on menu items.

I'm not sure how can I show the appropriate page from the Facelet because everytime I try it shows the first page on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**- The Menu bar and the page to redirect to are in the same portlet**

If the menu bar is in the JSF portlet, you have only to define a JSF navigation-rule in your faces-config.xml file to navigate to the new view.

For example, consider that ***home.xhtml*** is the main portlet view (default portlet view) and that doAction() is the method in the managedBean that handle the click on the menu.

```
public String doAction() {
   return "go_to_page";
}
```

and in the faces-config.xml

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>home.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>go_to_page</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>page.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

**- The Menu bar and the page to redirect to are *not* in the same portlet**

But if the menu is in another portlet and you don't want to redirect, you have to use IPC (inter portlet communication) to change the view of the JSF Portlet. [I wrote this tutorial](http://roufid.com/liferay-jsf-portlet-communication/) that may help you to perform the IPC between JSF portlets.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. it looks very useful. The thing is that we will have a menu panel out side and in that we will have all the menus. So the link which are in side panel should not be tied to jsf.  

I wonder if it is possible using friendly url?

Comment: Since you have **only one portlet with many Facelets pages and many backing beans**, using friendly url will not solve your problem. In fact it will only redirect to a new page in which the jsf portlet's view will remain the same _(the default view specified in the property javax.portlet.faces.defaultViewId.view in your portlet.xml)_.

Comment: You are right Radouane ROUFID. I have created few other portlets in the same war and it worked.

Comment: Note that your are not obliged to put all your portlets in the same war to perform the IPC. If you want, for some reasons, to separate your portlets in different war, you can do it and perform the IPC by adding the property **_portlet.public.render.parameter.distribution=layout-set_** into the **_portal-ext.properties_** file.